java streams complex groupingBy
I'm trying to use java streams to achieve the same logic I have below. Basically I'm trying to find out if in a collection I have 2 entries that have the same log id and tag more than once
class Log {
private String id;
private List<String> tags;
};

void findLogsWithSameTag(List<Log> logs) {

    final Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for ( var log : logs ) {
        for ( var tag : log.getTags() ) {
            Integer count = map.computeIfAbsent( log.getId(), key -> new HashMap<>())
                    .getOrDefault( tag, 0);
            map.get( log.getId() ).put( tag, count + 1 );
        }
    }

    for ( final var entry : map.entrySet() ) {
        for ( final var entry2 : entry.getValue().entrySet() ) {
            if ( entry2.getValue() > 1 ) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad!");
            }
        }
    }
}


I first tried to group the Logs by tags but I don't know how to flatMap the key to be a String instead of a List<String>. Then I tried to group by Log::getId but again I couldn't flatMap the tags to a String.
Does anyone knows how to do this with stream().groupingBy(...) ?
edit: Adding some examples:
// should throw as log1 has tag1 twice
List.of( 
    new Log("log1", List.of( "tag1", "tag2") )
    new Log("log1", List.of( "tag1") )
);


// should not throw as there is no tag more than once associated with an id
List.of( 
    new Log("log1", List.of( "tag1", "tag2") )
    new Log("log2", List.of( "tag1") )
);


It’s getting complex alright. Here is how it can be done. The question is whether it’s too complex to be readable. Thanks for the challenge anyway.

Integer count = map.computeIfAbsent( log.getId(), key -> new HashMap<>()) .getOrDefault( tag, 0); map.get( log.getId() ).put( tag, count + 1 ); is unnecessarily complicated. You can instead use map.computeIfAbsent( log.getId(), key -> new HashMap<>()) .merge(tag, 1, Integer::sum);

@Anonymous: I like your solution. Please consider posting it as an answer.

@IWilms Thanks. I am no longer contributing answers to Stack Overflow, except for very few exceptions. Users and moderators were deleting essential, even crucial information from my answers, I got tired of that. Feel free to post an answer using my code with appropriate explanation, and I shall be happy to upvote.

I would not use streams for this. But do use a set to detect duplicates.

Iterate over the list of logs.
for Each log instance, create a Map.Entry<String,String> to hold the id and each tag for that id.
and put each in a set.  If the set returns false, that indicates that id/tag pair has already been seen so it is a duplicate. You can throw and exception, print the entry, or whatever is appropriate.

Notice that it is not require to iterate over all the logs.  It terminates once a duplicate is found.
static void findLogsWithSameTag(List<Log> logs) {

    Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> seen = new HashSet<>();

    for (Log log : logs) {
        for (String tag : log.getTags()) {
            Map.Entry<String, String> e = Map.entry(log.getId(), tag);
            if (!seen.add(e)) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "Duplicate id(%s) and tag(%s)".formatted(e.getKey(),
                                e.getValue()));
            }
        }
    }
}

Note that this will also throw an exception if you have a single instance with two identical tags. e.g.
Log("log1", List.of("tag1", "tag2", "tag1")).  If that is a problem you can remove the duplicate tags within a log entry by modifying the inner loop as follows.

add the tags to a set to remove duplicates.
then iterate over that set instead of log.getTags()

Set<String> distinctTags = new HashSet<>(log.getTags());
for (String tag : distinctTags) {
...
...


I came up with this ugly piece of code using groupingBy:
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

class Log {
[...]
    record LogIdAndTag(String id, String tag) {}

    static Stream<LogIdAndTag> extractTags(Log log) {
        return log.tags()
                .stream()
                .map(tag -> new LogIdAndTag(log.id, tag));
    }

    static Map<String, Map<String, Long>> getLogToTagCount(List<Log> logs) {
        return logs.stream()
                .flatMap(Log::extractTags)
                .collect(groupingBy(
                        LogIdAndTag::id,
                        groupingBy(
                                LogIdAndTag::tag,
                                counting()
                        )
                ));
    }
}

You still need to iterate through the Map like you did in your solution and look for duplicates. Please see the comment of @Anonymous under your question for a nicer solution using groupingBy.
I find the following more readable:
static Optional<LogIdAndTag> findLogIdAndTagDuplicate(List<Log> logs) {
    HashSet<LogIdAndTag> seen = new HashSet<>();
    var notDistinct = Predicate.not(seen::add);

    return logs.stream()
            .flatMap(Log::extractTags)
            .filter(notDistinct)
            .findFirst();
}

According to the doc HashSet::add
returns

true if this set did not already contain the specified element

EDIT
The initial answer was completely wrong. Thanks for @davidalayachew for pointing that out.

Shouldn't it be Predicate.not(seen::add)?

While you are at it, could you add a comment explaining the seen::add? This is an excellent answer, but the subtlety of that line might go over a lot of people's heads. It went over mine on the first read through.

Thanks for pointing that out, you are completely right. @hashCode and @equals where also missing, so this would never have worked.

You can make use the fact that toMap throws an IllegalStateException when it encounters 2 values for a key.
try {
    logs.stream()
        .flatMap(l -> l.getTags().stream().map(t -> Map.entry(l.getId(), t)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), Function.identity());
} catch(IllegalStateException e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.toString());
}

However, as others pointed out, this is not a good use case for streams since it does not fails fast.

Sample data:
List<Log> logs1 = List.of( 
    new Log("log1", List.of( "tag1", "tag2")),
    new Log("log1", List.of( "tag1")),
    new Log("log9", List.of("tag9"))
);

List<Log> logs2 = List.of( 
    new Log("log1", List.of( "tag1", "tag2")),
    new Log("log2", List.of( "tag1")),
    new Log("log9", List.of("tag9"))
);

List<Log> logs3 = List.of( 
    new Log("log1", List.of( "tag1", "tag2")),
    new Log("log1", List.of( "tag3")),
    new Log("log9", List.of("tag9"))
);

From the above three input lists, only logs1 data throws an exception.
logs1.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getId()))
    .values()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.size() > 1)
    .flatMap(e -> e.stream())
    .flatMap(e -> e.tags.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()))
    .forEach((k, v) -> {
        if (v > 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Found bad data in the logs!");
        }
     });

